# While loop and cin char, int

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, cin

I'm just trying to figure out this:

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, x = 0;
  cin >> n;
  char s[3];

  while (n-- > 0) {
    cout << n << endl;
    // cin >> s;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I fill n with 2, everything works fine (`1` and `0` get printed), but if I uncomment the `cin >> s;` line, only first iteration (`1`) will be performed (and the input gets saved into `s`).

Now my question: why is working like that? And how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works as expected here. Try running it in a debugger.

Comment: I ran it at: https://www.codechef.com/ide and with input:

    2 (newline)
    X++ (newline)
    --X

Comment: @n.m. It *might* not run as expected, depending on input of *s*. It looks like classic buffer overflow, since s is only [3].

Comment: @bartek `looks like classic buffer overflow` *this* is expected too of course.

Comment: How many characters do you think are in the string `"X++"`? Hint: not three.

Comment: @n.m. exactly, adding +1 to buffer to include \0 makes this works, at least for 3 letters case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the useless declaration of variable **x**, I think there's nothing wrong with your code.

If n is filled with 2 the result is always 1 and 0 get printed, regardless the cin >> s; is uncommented or not.

Comment: Yeah, the `x = 0` is for later use, so no problem with that. The thing appears to be, as mentioned before, a buffer overflow in the input; still trying to debug it.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the buffer overflow, can't believe I missed that :(

Comment: There was a problem with my input (or the way the IDE I was using passed this), because a `freopen` did the trick.

Comment: If you need the input to be always integer, you can use it like in the answer on this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826281/how-do-i-make-a-c-program-that-filter-out-non-integers

Comment: Ok, in order to solve the problem I had to do `char s[4]`, so it accepts inputs like `X++` :)